# Why the word 'dereferencing' in terms of dereferencing pointers?

Tags: objective-c, c

I am wondering why 'dereferencing' is the term used when talking about accessing the value stored at a pointer. 
I'm just not getting why 'dereferencing' as a word is used. It might help to better embed the notion in my head if I can find out why.. thanks.

Comment: Pointers and references were once used for the same thing. A pointer points to memory but it is also referencing some data (some structure). Dereferencing means accessing that data. "dereference" = "remove the reference and access the data directly".

Comment: Getting to the content of what is being pointed to.

Comment: Thanks. I do understand the logic of how they work; dereferencing just feels odd as a word.

Comment: you might want to google pointers and referencing/dereferencing.  here is a typical wiki link: <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29>

Comment: First of all, that link is invalid. Second, I am well familiar with google. Third, I already said I understand pointers. It is the literal meaning of 'dereferencing' that I would like insight into: i.e Linguistically wise....